# OpenCV calculate covariance matrix with only one sample

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, covariance

I want to calculate the mean and the covariance matrix of samples. Is this possible even if the size of the sample is only 1? Because when I do:

```
calcCovarMatrix(descriptor, covar, mean, CV_COVAR_ROWS, CV_32F);
```

After execution the `covar` matrix is only 1x1 big and only contains `0` whereas `descriptor` is a row vector with 390 different float elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of what the *average* and *covariance* mean in this case. If you only have a single sample, then:

1. the average is your only sample
2. there is no sample at a non-zero distance from the average, hence the covariance is zero.

**Edit** Note that if you wanted to calculate the average and variance of the 390 float values, you need to use `CV_COVAR_COLUMNS` instead of `CV_COVAR_ROWS`.

Comment: CV_COVAR_COLUMNS, are you sure? Even when my descriptor is a row vector?

Comment: @user3236180 As I said, what you should do depend on what you expect as a result... What exactly do you want to compute the (co)variance from?

Comment: I want to compute it from the descriptor matrix, which can sometimes contain one sample and sometimes even 100 samples. But all samples are stored as rows in the matrix.

Comment: @user3236180 so you want to compute the average and the covariance matrix of the 1x390 descriptor vectors, not of the 390 float values, hence the right flag is `CV_COVAR_ROWS`.